# Show and hide table CELLS when user searches for ONE CELL

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have this piece of jQuery code. When a user searches for a string present in the table, the code hides all rows and only shows the row in which the searched string is present. The problem is that I have 4x4 table like this:

```
 a|b|c|d| 
 e|f|g|h|
 i|j|k|l|
 m|n|o|p|
```

Thus, when I look for 'a', it will show the whole first row!

```
 a|b|c|d|
```

I would like a way for it to hide all CELLS that don't contain 'a' inside, like this;
    |a|

How could I change the code below? Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#search').keyup(function()
            {
                searchTable($(this).val());
            });
        });
        function searchTable(inputVal)
        {
            var table = $('#tblData');
            table.find('tr').each(function(index, row)
            {
                var allCells = $(row).find('td');
                if(allCells.length > 0)
                {
                    var found = false;
                    allCells.each(function(index, td)
                    {
                        var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
                        if(regExp.test($(td).text()))
                        {
                            found = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    if(found == true)$(row).show();else $(row).hide();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the row with `if(found == true)$(row).show();else $(row).hide();`.

If you want to hide individual cells you need to show/hide the `$(td)` element where you found your match.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#search').keyup(function()
   {
    searchTable($(this).val());
  });
});
function searchTable(inputVal)
{
  console.log(inputVal);
  var table = $('#tblData');
  table.find('tr').each(function(index, row)
  {
    var allCells = $(row).find('td');
    if(allCells.length > 0)
    {
      var found = false;
      allCells.each(function(index, td)
      {
        var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
        if(regExp.test($(td).text())) // if found show the cell else hide
          $(td).show(); 
        else
          $(td).hide();
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 4px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" placeholder="search"/>
<table id="tblData">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>e</td><td>f</td><td>g</td><td>h</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td><td>l</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>m</td><td>n</td><td>o</td><td>p</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to really simplify your `searchTable` function and get the behavior you're looking for with [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and [`contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/).

```js
$(function() {
  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    searchTable($(this).val());
  });
});

function searchTable(inputVal) {
 $('#tblData td').show();
 $('#tblData td:not(:contains(' + inputVal + '))').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search">
<table id="tblData" class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
      <td>p</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```